# Changing layout files for a fragment during runtime

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to develop an app in which fragments are involved. There are 2 fragments on screen. The list fragment containing a Start and Stop button and a detail fragment on the right side. On click of the Start button an audio processing code runs in the detail fragment. So depending on the result i get out of the process I want to change the layout of the fragment. Basically I want to change the layout file of a single fragment during run time depending on the results I get while doing some process. How can I achieve it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot switch to a different layout file in a fragment, the view you returned from `onCreateView` cannot be replaced.

However, you have several options:

- You can show and hide views at runtime with [View.setVisibility()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29).
- [ViewStubs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html) can be inflated at a later time.
- Or you could replace your detail fragment with a new fragment.

Comment: Ok thanks i will try the first  two. Anyways I cannot replace my detail fragment with a new one.

Comment: @user1957734 Did the answer help?

Comment: hi..brillrnheini.. since i had to finish my task a little faster i dropped the idea of changing layout files depending on the result. I just displayed the result using a toast message.